# I don't know why this python code for replacing all occurences of a substring not working

Tags: python, string

```
#program to replace all occurences of a substring with a given substring!!!!

def replace_string(str,x,y):
    a = len(x)
    for i in range(len(str)):
        if str[i] == x[0]:   
            end = i+a
            sub_str = str[i:end]
            if x == sub_str:
                str = str[:i] + y + str[end:]
            else:
                continue
        else:
            continue
    print (str)

str = input("enter a string- ")
x = input("Input substring to be deleted- ")
y = input("Enter substring to be fit in- ")
replace_string(str,x,y)
```

**These are some outputs it gives**

1.

```
enter a string- abcabcddabc
Input substring to be deleted- abc
Enter substring to be fit in- haha
```

->`hahahahaddhaha`

2.

```
enter a string- i am a good boy
Input substring to be deleted-<space> 
Enter substring to be fit in- "
```

->`i"am"a"good"boy`

But when i put the same string "I am a good boy" but i try to replace good with bad, it gives an error of index out of range but i am not able to understand why this is coming....

```
enter a string- i am a good boy
Input substring to be deleted- good
Enter substring to be fit in- bad
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:/----/-----/---------/Fn_replace.py", line 19, in <module>
    replace_string(str,x,y)
  File "f:/----/-----/--------/Fn_replace.py", line 5, in replace_string
    if str[i] == x[0]:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

**PLEASE HELP**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the new string `bad` is shorter than `good`. For debugging purpose, I add a padding character `^` to see the difference.

```
def replace_string(str,x,y):
    if len(y)<len(x):
        y += "^"*(len(x)-len(y))   #add padding
    a = len(x)
    for i in range(len(str)):
        if str[i] == x[0]:   
            end = i+a
            sub_str = str[i:end]
            if x == sub_str:
                str = str[:i] + y + str[end:]
            else:
                continue
        else:
            continue
    print (str)
```

Output:

```
enter a string-  i am a good boy
Input substring to be deleted-  good
Enter substring to be fit in-  bad
i am a bad^ boy
```

If you change the print statement to `print(str.replace("^", ""))`, the new output would be

```
enter a string-  i am a good boy
Input substring to be deleted-  good
Enter substring to be fit in-  bad
i am a bad boy
```

For learning purpose, you could use the function `.replace()` to achieve your end goal

```
def replace_string(s,x,y):
    print(s.replace(x, y))

s = input("enter a string- ")
x = input("Input substring to be deleted- ")
y = input("Enter substring to be fit in- ")
replace_string(s,x,y)
```

Output

```
enter a string-  i am a good boy
Input substring to be deleted-  good
Enter substring to be fit in-  bad
i am a bad boy
```

P/S: Also, please follow @Sujay's advice: do not use 'str' as variable name, because it is a python function, example `str(x)`

Comment: he could use the function he made to do this too :-) by using spaces

Comment: @AdityaGupta, yea that's right! Input `good` and `bad `(with a space), making sure both have the same char length

Answer (score 1):

The length of `bad` isn't equal to `good` hence the error. Also, `str` is inbuilt function in python so don't use it as a variable. I suggest a simple program here.

```
strr = input("enter a string- ")
x = input("Input substring to be deleted- ")
y = input("Enter substring to be fit in- ")
strr=strr.replace(x,y)
print(strr)
```

Example:

```
strr=hello hello boys
x=hello
y=f

Output: f f hello
```

Comment: But the main task was to do this without replace function.. BTW Thanks